# Reached maximum VM restart count for {nombre_vm}

Tags: vmware-esx, virtual-machines

We have 4 ESX Server in cluster. Yesterday i received this warning in all VM: Reached maximum VM restart count for {vm_name}. We can´t do VMotion and others tasks whit these machines.
Any idea? what we can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Licenses do you have installed. I have found, that VMware is moving some Products to Guest based licences. For example the Vmware Enterprise you get with VMware View only allow up to a certain  limit of guests to be running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using HA in your cluster. Maybe the VM's don't meet the Fault Tolerance.

Have you tried do deactivate HA and try to move the VM's to another Host?

If everything is alright with the cluster (hardware, licenses) I would just deactivate HA, wait a few minutes and activate HA again.